# Twig check if value is in array

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig, saas

I'm having trouble to check if a value is present in an array with Twig.
I want to hide a shipping method in a checkout if there's a certain product in the cart. 
**I can only use `Twig` code so I have to find a logic in that.**

So let's say when product ID 1234 is in cart then I want to hide `#certain_div`

So what I have is this ->

```
  {% if checkout %}

      {% set array = theme.sku_shipping_rule | split(',') %}
     // theme.sku_shipping_rule = a text string like 1234, 4321, 5478         

        {% if checkout.products %}
         {% for product in checkout.products %}
          {% if product.sku in array %}

           <style>
             #certain_div {
                display: none;
              }
           </style>

          {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
       {% endif %}

    {% endif %}
```

The problem I'm facing is that it seems my code always returns true. So even if the `product.sku` doens't match a value in the array it still hides `#certain_div`. I've tested that with placing `{{ product.sku }}` just before `<style>`.

What do I wrong?

Any help greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

I've updated the question/code to show what's happening

```
{% if checkout %}
    {% set skuToCheck = theme.sku_shipping_rule | split(',') %}
    {% set skuInCart = [] %}
    {% if checkout.quote.products %}
        {% for product in checkout.quote.products %}
            {% set skuInCart = skuInCart | merge([product.sku]) %}
        {% endfor %}
     {% endif %}

     {% for myVar in skuInCart %}
         {{ myVar }}<br/>
     {% endfor %}

     // this prints
     PSYGA1 // where this sku should NOT match
     FP32MA4

    {% for myVar in skuToCheck  %}  
        {{ myVar }}<br/>

        // this prints
        FP32LY4
        FP32STR4
        FP32MA4   

        {% if myVar in skuInCart %} // also tried with | keys filter
            {{ myVar }} is found
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

So what I did is placing the sku's from the products which are in the cart in an array `skuInCart`. Next I want to check if `myVar` is present in the `skuInCart` array. If so print `myVar is found`.

What happens is that you should expect that it prints only the matching results. However it actually prints all values present `skuInCart` (using `keys` filter) or completely blank without using `keys` filter.

Comment: Your code as written should evaluate the way you think.  How do you know that it is always returning true?  I'm guessing that the problem is related to the fact that you are outputting a style block inside of a loop.

Comment: I have to agree with GentlemanMax, your code should work, seem like this could be an overlapping style issue. Are you changing what `certain_div` is? because if you are applying that to all the divs that would be problematic in 2 ways. One that IDs are meant to be unique and 2 that you are applying styles to elements you may not mean to.

Comment: @GentlemanMax: I've updated my question to show what's happening. Have any of you any input on that? Thanks....

Comment: @Chausser: See my updated answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing in theory should work, have a look a this fiddle example to show you a working demonstration:

https://twigfiddle.com/yvpbac

Basically:

```
<div id="certain_div">
This should not show up
</div>

{% set searchForSku = "890" %}
{% set productSkuArrayString = "1234,4567,890" %}
{% set productSkuArray = productSkuArrayString|split(',') %}
{% if searchForSku in productSkuArray %}
<style>
    #certain_div {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
{% endif %}

<!-- New Trial -->

<div id="certain_div">
This should show up
</div>

{% set searchForSku = "891" %}
{% set productSkuArrayString = "1234,4567,890" %}
{% set productSkuArray = productSkuArrayString|split(',') %}
{% if searchForSku in productSkuArray %}
<style>
    #certain_div {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
{% endif %}
```

Will result in:

```
<div id="certain_div">
This should not show up
</div>

<style>
    #certain_div {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<!-- New Trial -->

<div id="certain_div">
This should show up
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`iterable`](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tests/iterable.html) to check if a variable is an array or a traversable object:

```
{% if items is iterable %}
  {# stuff #}
{% endif %}
```